# Extending elasticSearch class on Es6 not working

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, ecmascript-6, es6-class

Probably I'm doing something wrong ( or getting the wrong idea on the extends implementation ) but why can't I add methods extending the elasticsearch.Client ( https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/issues/516 ) class?

```
class MyClass extends elasticsearch.Client {

    constructor(config) {
        super(config);       

       this.testConnection(); //-> gives an this.testConnection is undefined
    }

    testConnection() {
        this.ping({
            requestTimeout: 30000,
        }, (error) => {
            if(error) console.error('Elastic search is out');
            if(!error) {
                console.log('Conected');
            }
        });
    }
}

const client = new MyClass({
    host: 'my_host', 
    log: 'info'
});

MyClass.testConnection(); //also an "undefined" error
```

Ps: The super method is called since I have a "Elastic info connected" message

Comment: Judging by the source code in their repo, their client is not written using ES6.  If you want to accomplish the same thing, you could require their client, add properties to it for your functionality, and then export it again.

Comment: @ryanlutgen it's written in Typescript. Would that be the issue?

Comment: You project is in TypeScript?  Are you trying to run your code in a browser then (I assume so if you're using TS)?  You can try my suggestion of requiring the client requiring their client (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/blob/master/src/lib/client.js) and adding to the object to see if it works.  You would need a build tool like webpack to get all of the relevant code included.

Comment: Actually I'm using Nodejs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from them. If it helps anyone just click here:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/issues/516